# Delegates vs Method overiding

Tags: c#, delegates, overriding

What is the advantage of using **Delegates** over **Method overriding** in Object oriented Programming **c#**

Comment: whats an example use case?wheres the code? I don't understand your question... delegates are not the same as method overriding..

Comment: These are some entirely different things. Can you give an example?

Comment: In what way are these two interchangeable?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: One of my friend have faced this question in a interview. I got dumbstruck for a while and thought of getting clarity from bigger community f i'm missing anything